# how to find the raw html from a tag which is itself find by using xpath

Tags: xpath, lxml, innerhtml

I have get elements by XPath as follows. This found all `<tr>` tags. The `<tr>` elements have some content. How can I get the HTML of a single `tr` element?

```
tbody = tbody_element1[0].xpath('.//tbody')
if tbody:
    tr_value = tbody[0].xpath('.//tr')
```

`tr_value` is an array  of *all* `tr` elements inside the `tbody` element.

Comment: `tr_value = tbody[0].xpath('.//tr')[0]` could work.

Comment: if we do this so now we have  first value of array in tr_value now , but does this contain data in raw html form or  xpath() return some thing else....?

Comment: actually i find elements upto  tr tag by lxml and now tr tag contains some  html tags inside it , so for this html tag i want to use Beautiful soup . How  can we do this ..?

Comment: thank you Lutz Horn ....

Answer (score 0):

To obtain raw html I use etree

```
if tbody:
    tr_value = tbody[0].xpath('.//tr')
raw_value = etree.tostring(tr_value[0])
```

now **raw_value** have html content which is contains by **tr_value**